# Why does Jenkins pipeline Stage View show red for all stages if only one stage failed?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I noticed that if any pipeline stage fails then all previous stages show red.  Is it possible to control the color of previous stages so they are green regardless of subsequent stages?  My last stage catches an error.  If you hover over any previous stage it says 'success' but shows red.  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a build can only be successful or failed. There is no such thing as a partially successful build. The stage shows you where it probably failed but nothing more, you still have a 0 or 1.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but that seems to defeat the purpose of a pipeline with stages.  It seems like you should be able to control the workflow by setting colors to each stage.  I guess I'll hold out hope for https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/26/introducing-blue-ocean/

Comment: I know that is a bit confusing from the visual point of view and I hope too that the blue ocean will address all of these.